# Webdriverio with chrome browser does not display correcty

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I am currently trying to test an app using webdriverio and chrome. But the app does not display anything but the images and some borders (??)(see pic). I get the same behaviour also with other websites, so it is not a problem of the app under test. Everything also displays well using other browsers (e.g firefox)

[how it displays in chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mercd.png)

Update: after searching a little bit more, I think this has something to do with passing basic auth credentials in the url, because the page I am testing is password protected. I have this in the webdriverio config file:

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--disable-blink-features=BlockCredentialedSubresources']
    }
}]
```

I am also using *selenium-standalone* as a service, version *0.0.10*, webdriverio version *4.13.1*.

In my code I open the page using:

```
browser.url("https://user:password@mywebsite.com/kontakt/");
```

Comment: Can you show your code, and version of webdriverio, chromedriver, Chrome browser?

Comment: Sure! I updated the post with relevant informations about my setup